# Fazer uma consulta SQL que retorne os valores contidos em duas tabelas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu preciso realizar uma consulta neste banco de dados que liste o nome de todos os cursos e seus respectivos alunos, em ordem decrescente pelo nome dos cursos? porém não faço a menor ideia de como fazer, eu estudei um pouco o conceito de JOIN, mas na prática não consegui implementar, segue o código SQL.

```
create database faculdade;
use faculdade;
create table aluno(
  idAluno int primary key not null,
  matricula varchar(10) not null,
  nomeAluno varchar(50) not null
);
create table disciplina(
  idDisciplina int primary key not null,
  nome varchar(50) not null,
  cargaHoraria int not null
);
create table historico(
  idAluno int not null,
  idDisciplina int not null,
  nota float(3) not null,
  dataHistorico date not null,
  constraint fkidAluno foreign key(idAluno) 
  references aluno(idAluno),
  constraint fkidDisciplina foreign 
  key(idDisciplina) references 
  disciplina(idDisciplina)
);
create table curso(
  idCurso int primary key not null,
  nomeCurso varchar(50)
);
create table alunoCurso(
  idAluno int not null,
  idCurso int not null,
  anoEntrada int not null,
  constraint fkidAlunoCurso foreign key (idAluno) 
  references aluno(idAluno),
  constraint fkidCurso foreign key (idCurso) 
  references curso(idCurso)
);
create table grade(
  idGrade int primary key not null,
  idCurso int not null,
  ano int not null,
  cargaHorariaTotal int not null,
  constraint fkidCursoGrade foreign key (idCurso) 
  references curso(idCurso)
);
create table gradeDisciplina(
  idGrade int not null,
  idDisciplina int not null,
  constraint fkidGrade foreign key (idGrade) 
  references grade(idGrade),
  constraint fkidGradeDisciplina foreign key 
  (idDisciplina) references 
  disciplina(idDisciplina)
);
```

O código que usei ficou assim;

```
select c.nomeCurso, a.nomeAluno 
FROM curso c, aluno a  
inner join alunoCurso ac on ac.idAluno = a.idAluno 
order by nomeCurso desc;
```

Comment: Como você sabe que determinado aluno pertence a um determinado curso olhando para as tabelas que existem?

Comment: Através das fk idAluno e IdCurso na tabela aluno curso, que recebem os ids do curso e do aluno.

Comment: Então não acha que o SELECT deveria abranger essa tabela?

Comment: Sim deveria, porém é ai que está o meu problema, apesar de ter estudado um pouco sobre o assunto não consegui implementar da forma correta. Vou tentar fazer mais alguns testes.

Comment: usando um select desta maneira, faz a lista porém a minha dúvida é, esta é a forma correta de se fazer isto, ou é uma "Gambiarra"?  obs(Não sei adicionar códigos no comentário).                                                                     
    `select nomeCurso, nomeAluno from
    curso, aluno order by nomeCurso desc;`

Comment: Vc precisa incluir `alunoCurso` no `select`, e fazer `join` com as tabelas `aluno` e `curso` para obter os nomes. Pesquise por `JOIN`, um bom ponto de partida é esse: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/112052

Comment: esse join não faz sentido, ele tem a sintaxe errada (é preciso informar por qual coluna as tabelas se relacionam), e aluno x curso não se ligam diretamente, pelo seu modelo, precisa usar a tabela "alunoCurso" no `join`. O erro acontece pq está usando "nome" no `select` e no `join`, eles conflitam, por isso o erro é de "ambigous", o seja, o banco de dados não consegue "resolver" a que o nome se refere

Comment: Não sei qual o procedimento padrão para solução se é editando a pergunta ou via comentário. Portanto irei responder via comentário mesmo. Eu usei o JOIN da seguinte forma:                                           
`select curso.nomeCurso, aluno.nomeAluno from curso, aluno inner join alunoCurso on aluno.idAluno=idCurso order by nomeCurso desc;`                                                       para finalizar se alguém puder responder, neste formato ele atende aquilo que eu preciso. Está correto assim? Fiz algumas alterações no banco, se necessário edito apergunta com o código corrigido.

Comment: Está errado. Deveria ser algo como `select c.nome, a.nome from aluno a inner join alunoCurso ac on a.idAluno=ac.idAluno inner join curso c on c.idCurso = ac.idCurso order by c.nome desc`. Repare que para o join com `aluno` vc tem que usar o `idAluno` em ambas as tabelas, e fazer outro join com `curso` - e também usei alias nas tabelas pra ficar mais curto. Outra coisa, a coluna se chama apenas `nome` e não `nomeCurso` (a menos que vc tenha mudado e não atualizou na pergunta).